# PrimeNG fieldset not closing on load of page

Tags: angular, primeng, fieldset

I am using `PrimeNG` to display `Feildset` and following below example

```
<p-fieldset legend="Test Data" [toggleable]="true">
    My Data
</p-fieldset>
```

If I assign `false` to `[toggleable]` property then it is not working as toggleable. IT should be exapnd when user clicks on toggle. Default it should be close.

Any other way to do it? Also tried with `collapsed` property but no luck.

[PRimeNG Feildset](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fieldset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `[collapsed]=false`

> collapsed - Defines the default visibility state of the content.

I created a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2xjcai?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) with a working example:

Comment: Ok. Let me try, actually I have multiple field-sets on one page.